# C# Firebase realtime database

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database

I need nugget package for Firebase real time database.
According https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#windows
Firebase admin sdk is not supporting real time database for c#.

When i go to Database Secrets in Firebase settings, it says:
"Database secrets are currently deprecated and use a legacy Firebase token generator. Update your source code with the Firebase Admin SDK."

What nugget package can i use for c# to manage real time database Rest API?

- I'm using for now Install-Package FirebaseDatabase.net

but Firebase saying that it's deprecated (You can see message above).